# auditing mod security rule sets

Tags: linux, windows, mod-security

Is there a audit system that can help me try my strings? Such as user agents, post/get data, a simple way to test general sql injections to see how my rule sets hold?

I know with fire fox I can change my user agent but what about trying post and get type attacks?

Answer (score 3):

You should test your code in a real world scenario with a web application scanner like [skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/).    You could also try manually exploiting [Damn Vulnerable Web App](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/).

Tamperdata can be used to build and modify requests.  Or just plain old html.